# Quarkus - could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

This is my code for doing a request with jax-rs Client:

```
private Client client;

private static final int TIMEOUT = 8000;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .readTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
}
```

....

```
final String resource = "/some-endpoint/{id}/securityinfo";
final String path = url + resource;

final WebTarget target = client
        .target(path)
        .resolveTemplate("id", email);

final var form = new Form().param("mail", email);

final Response response = target
        .request()
        .post(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));

if (response.getStatusInfo().getFamily() != Response.Status.Family.SUCCESSFUL) {
    throw new MyException(response.readEntity(String.class));
}
```

I receive the error:

> javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request:  javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: javax.ws.rs.core.Form

This happens only with form - content type request, as the json support works properly.

**EDIT**

These are the dependencies used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-oracle</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#form-javax.ws.rs.core.Form-) :

```
Entity.form(form);
```

I'm not sure it will fix the issue as it is just shorthand for what you have. But i would give it a try.

In order to find a solution easier can you share the dependencies you are using on your project.

Comment: Yes I tried. Actually that form is a shortcut of Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)

Comment: Can you share the dependencies you have on your quarkus project. I never used WebTarget with quarkus as their default option is RestClient.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: How are you setting up your client, i tried to use your code and didn't get the issue.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I researched a bit regarding this and I think the issue is that the client you are using is not  a ResteasyClient which supports this type of operation natively. I never used it so i was trying to create a demo project to show you how to do it using RestClient which is the preferred approach in quarkus. However i don't have much time, so please take a look at their documentation here https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client. If you follow it correctly it should work and you will have much cleaner code as a bonus.